# Can you use stochastic gradient descent with a multinomial likelihood?

Tags: machine-learning, multinomial-distribution, online-algorithms, stochastic-gradient-descent

I have a multinomial likelihood of the form:

$$P(\underline n|\underline x) = N!\prod_{i=1}^M \frac{f_i(\underline x)^{n_i}}{n_i!}$$

where $\underline x$ is a vector of parameters, $f_i(\underline x)\ge0$, $\sum_i f_i(\underline x)=1$. The data vector $\underline n$ consists of non-negative integers $n_i$ satisfying $\sum_i n_i=N$.

I intend to infer the parameters $\underline x$ by maximizing $P(\underline n|\underline x)$. Note that the number of parameters is smaller than $M$, so we can't just invert $f_i(\underline x) = n_i/N$, but rather need to do a numerical maximization of the likelihood (or posterior if one wishes to include a prior/regularization term).

Here $M$ can be very large, so I want to know if there is a variant of online learning or stochastic gradient descent that I can exploit, so that I can take steps where only one observation $i$ is used.

But either this is not possible or I don't know what keywords to use to search google, or maybe I am missing a simple trick. Every theorem I've seen on the convergence of stochastic gradient descent assumes that the examples are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible trick that I think can work. But I am open to comments.

We can write (I think this is called the Poisson-Multinomial trick):

$$P(\underline n|\underline x) \propto P^*(\underline n|\underline x) = \prod_i\frac{f_i(\underline x)^{n_i}}{n_i!}\mathrm{e}^{-f_i(\underline x)}$$

From the point of view of the inference, it makes no difference that the data $\underline n$ are generated according to $P(\underline n|\underline x)$ or to $P^*(\underline n|\underline x)$, because they only differ in a proportionality constant that is independent of the parameters $\underline x$. But in $P^*(\underline n|\underline x)$ the $n_i$ can be viewed as drawn from independent Poisson distributions with rates $f_i(\underline x)$.

Since under $P^*(\underline n|\underline x)$ we have independence, we can apply standard SGD or Adam or related online learning algorithms to the modified likelihood, feeding the $i$'s one by one, and all the usual convergence theorems will apply.

If someone reads this please let me know what you think and if it seems correct.